# Generalizing the multiple processes in flow chart diagram

Tags: etl, flowchart

Below is  a general ETL flow chart diagram.I am really confused if it is a good practice to draw such a flow chart.Especially at lines connecting the final output , and the big box used to generalize the whole process that goes from input format to 'Validate files  as per type of file' to 'Adjustments for desired output' and finally to 'outputs'.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

In concept, to provide an overview of the process, a Context diagram or Data Flow Diagram can be used as well as a Flow Chart. While all these diagrams are old, they are usually useful.

I suggest that you check the following points in your diagram - What I have here are personal suggestions based on long history with ETL.

1. Your processing shape (say rectangle) must have at least one entry (input) and at least one exist(output). Example: The two large rectangles don't have clear inputs and outputs! What is going on there?
2. You can't have outputs without a process - Example: Type 1 is somehow split into Type 1.1 and Type 1.2. How is that split happened? Is it by a program? Which one? Another example is Type 1.1 has an arrow connected to Output 1. Again same questions hold. Another example is "Rejected folder" to email.
3. The name of the process should indicate what the process is or the actual program component name or physical file names. This is valuable in ETL.
4. You may want to show the process triggering event such as time of day.
5. Use remarks.
6. Make the level of detail consistent.

Comment: Please note the point 1. It would be really complex and crowded if we define one box for each process, that is why I have used a single box.

Comment: The more you abstract the more the truth is hidden. It all depends on who wants to know what. That is why context diagrams are supposed to be general not detailed.

Comment: So this diagram is a good diagram if the intentions is just to show a general flow , rather than showing the details .

Comment: In my opinion, at least implement points 1, 2 and 3 so that it would be considered 'good'.